# Proving Cauchy's theorem (group theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ a prime number. Prove that $G$
>   contains an element of order $p$ if $p$ divides $|G|$. (Hint: reduce
>   to the situation where $G$ is cyclic and of order $p^r$)

Suppose $|G|=p^r m$ where $p\nmid m$. By considering a Sylow $p$-subgroup, we have a subgroup of order $p^r$. But how can I reduce to where the group is cyclic? (I'm trying to follow the hint in the problem)

Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128001/what-is-an-intuitive-way-to-think-of-cauchys-theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any element in your Sylow $p$-subgroup generates a cyclic group of $p$th-power order.  An element of order $p$ in this cyclic group is an element of order $p$ in the Sylow subgroup.

Comment: Thanks! So is this a proper explanation? I said that  This $p$-subgroup contains only elements of order $1,p,\cdots,p^r$. If it contains an element of order $p^r$, then it is cyclic and thus contains a subgroup of order $p$ because $p\mid p^r$. Then it would contain an element of order $p$ to generate that subgroup. But if $G$ does not contain an element of order $p^r$ then it may contain an element of order $p^{r-1}$ which generates the cyclic group of order $p^{r-1}$. (..etc..) Using inductive reasoning, there must be an element of order $p$ in the group $G$.

Comment: @PatrickShambayati: There is no need for induction.  You can assume there is some element $g$ of $p$th-power order (say $p^d$ where $d\le r$) so then $g^{p^{d-1}}$ has order $p$.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy proof of this due to McKay. Consider the set
$$ S = \{(a_1,\ldots,a_p) \in G^p : a_1\cdots a_p = e\}. $$
Also, define $A = \{x \in G : x^p = e\}$.
Clearly $|S| = |G|^{p-1}$. Every non-constant vector in $S$ has $p$ shifts (including itself) also in $S$, and so $p \mid |S| - |A|$. Since $p \mid |G|$, we conclude that $p \mid |A|$, and in particular $|A| \geq p$ (since $e \in A$). Apart from $e$, all other elements in $A$ have order $p$.