# Existence of a strange Group

Tags: group-theory

It seems to me that if $G$ is a finite group and $|G| \geq 3$ and odd then there exists an element $a \in G$ such that $a \neq a^{-1}$. I can easily show this for order $3$ and $5$ but for higher orders the computations become unwieldy.

**My attempt:**

> I want to prove this by contradiction. I assumed the existence of such a group and proved that it must be abelian. Let $a_{1},a_{2},\dots,a_{n}$ be precisely the sequence of elements in $G$ I think that $a_{1}a_{2}\dots a_{n}\neq a_{k}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n$ (This will show that the group operation is not closed) because if it's the case $a_{1}\dots a_{k-1}a_{k+1} \dots a_{n} = e$ where e is the identity element of the group $G$. How to obtain the contradiction from here onwards is where I  am stuck.

Comment: Maybe Cauchy's Theorem could help out.

Comment: Why such a title? is that so strange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G$ has odd order $n$, there is a prime $p>2$ dividing $n$. By [Cauchy's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177795/proving-cauchys-theorem-group-theory), there exists an element $a\in G$ of order $p$. Hence $a^2\neq e$ so that $a\neq a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

No need for contradiction: if  $|G|$ is odd, such an element either is $e$ or has order $2$, which is impossible by *Lagrange's theorem*.

Answer (score 3):

$a= a^{-1}$, i.e. $a^2 =1$. So if we assume there is no such $a$, every element has order $1$ or $2$. From Lagrange the order should divide $|G|$, i.e. every element has order $1$. But there is only one identity in group.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a=a^{-1}$ for every element of $G$, $a^2=1$. There exists a subgroup $H$  of order $p$ of $G$ where $p$ is an odd prime. Let $x$ be a generator of $H$, write $p=2m+1$, $x^p=1=x^{2m+1}=x^{2m}x=x$ contradiction.