# Let $|G|=2n$, show that there exists a $g\neq e$ such that $g^2=e$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group with $|G|=2n$ $(n\in \mathbb{N})$.

I have to show that for $g\in G$ with $g\neq e$ and $g^2=e$.

A hint says that I have to use the orbit-stabilizer theorem and interpret $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ as a group operation where $\{-1,1\}$ operates on $G$.

How can I construct that group operation?

I suppose $\gamma : \{-1,1\}\times G\to G, \, (a,g)\mapsto g^{a}$, where $a=1$ for $g\in G$ and $a=-1$ for $g^{-1}\in G$.

The Orbit-stabilizer theorem says $$2=|\{-1,1\}|=|\operatorname{Orb}_{\{-1,1\}}(x))|\cdot |\operatorname{Stab}_{\{-1,1\}}(x))|$$ This is where I am stuck, how does this prove the statement?

Comment: Another hint, for a slightly different, though essentially equivalent approach. Reinterpret the problem in terms of fixed points of the map $g \mapsto g^{-1}$.

Comment: You have $2n$ elements, where for $e$ you have only one element in the orbit. Thus there is some other element that only has one element in the orbit, now what does that tell you about the element?

Answer (score 2):

If $g\neq g^{-1}, \forall g(\neq e)\in G$,then $|G|=2k+1$,so there be exist $g(\neq e) $ such that $g^2=e$.

Answer (score 2):

For $p=2$, $p$ divides $|G|$, so that $G$ has an element $g$ of order $2$ by [Cauchy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177795/proving-cauchys-theorem-group-theory).

Answer (score 1):

What is says: the orbits are either of size $2$ or $1$. They are of size $1$ if and only if $g=g^{-1}$, that is $g^2=e$. Since $|G|$ is even, the number of orbits of size $1$ is even. There exists at least the orbit of size $1$, consisting of $e$. So there must exist another one.  All in all, the number of elements of order $2$ must be odd.

Answer (score 1):

Take all the elements of your group and match them up with their inverses:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c}
e&g_1&g_2&\cdots&\\ \hline
?&g_1^{-1}&g_2^{-1}&\cdots&\\
\end{array}$

Do you see how this forces at least one element to be its own inverse?